How to generate QR code and inject it to document before printing it in python
I want to make up a script in any language to catch the print job of a document and print a dynamically generated QR Code on it before the print job is processed. Is there any solutions ?
I already developed a Python script but, its not working as intended. I want any recommendations to make this script work or to use any other approaches to achieve the needed result.
 import win32print
import win32api
import tempfile
import os
import time
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import qrcode
import ctypes
import sys

processed_jobs = set()  # Track processed jobs

def is_admin():
    """Check if the script is running as an administrator."""
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

def generate_qr_code(data):
    """Generate a QR code image."""
    print("Generating QR code...")
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=10,
        border=4,
    )
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    qr_image = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    print("QR code generated successfully.")
    return qr_image

def inject_qr_to_document(original_doc, qr_image):
    """Inject QR code into the original document and preview it."""
    print("Injecting QR code into the original document...")
    qr_size = 300
    qr_position = (original_doc.width - qr_size - 50, original_doc.height - qr_size - 50)
    qr_image = qr_image.resize((qr_size, qr_size))
    original_doc.paste(qr_image, qr_position)
    print("QR code injected successfully.")
    
    # Preview the modified document
    print("Previewing the modified document...")
    original_doc.show()  # This will open the image in the default image viewer
    
    return original_doc

def cancel_print_job(printer_name, job_id):
    """Cancel the print job."""
    print(f"Cancelling print job ID {job_id} on printer {printer_name}...")
    try:
        # Open printer handle
        hprinter = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)

        # Cancel the print job using SetJob
        win32print.SetJob(hprinter, job_id, 0, None, win32print.JOB_CONTROL_DELETE)
        print(f"Print job {job_id} cancelled successfully.")

        # Close printer handle
        win32print.ClosePrinter(hprinter)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to cancel print job {job_id}: {e}")

def process_print_job(printer_name, job_id, qr_data):
    """Process the print job, inject QR code, and preview the modified document."""
    print(f"Processing print job with ID {job_id} on printer {printer_name}...")

    try:
        # Generate QR code
        qr_image = generate_qr_code(qr_data)

        # Create a simulated document for the example
        original_doc = Image.new("RGB", (2480, 3508), "white")  # A simulated A4 page
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(original_doc)
        draw.text((100, 100), f"Document: Simulated Content", fill="black")

        # Inject QR code into document and preview
        modified_doc = inject_qr_to_document(original_doc, qr_image)

        # Save the modified document to a temporary file
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix=".bmp") as temp_file:
            modified_doc.save(temp_file.name, "BMP")
            print(f"Modified document saved to: {temp_file.name}")
        
        # Note: You can send this modified file to the printer if needed, but for this case, we stop here.
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing print job: {e}")

def monitor_printer(printer_name, qr_data):
    """Monitor the printer for new print jobs."""
    print(f"Monitoring printer: {printer_name}...")
    hprinter = win32print.OpenPrinter(printer_name)
    try:
        while True:
            jobs = win32print.EnumJobs(hprinter, 0, -1, 1)
            for job in jobs:
                job_id = job["JobId"]
                if job_id not in processed_jobs:
                    processed_jobs.add(job_id)
                    print(f"New job detected: ID {job_id}")
                    cancel_print_job(printer_name, job_id)  # Cancel the original job
                    process_print_job(printer_name, job_id, qr_data)
            time.sleep(5)  # Check periodically
    finally:
        win32print.ClosePrinter(hprinter)
        print("Stopped monitoring.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Ensure the script runs with administrative privileges
    if not is_admin():
        print("Restarting with administrator privileges...")
        ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
        sys.exit()

    try:
        print("Initializing script...")
        default_printer = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
        print(f"Default printer detected: {default_printer}")
        qr_data = "Cairo Exchange Coprporate"
        monitor_printer(default_printer, qr_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
